# Can I safely unplug external HD when machine is suspended?

Tags: suspend, external-hdd

Does the suspend process **in Ubuntu** (12.04) unmount the partitions on the external hard drive, and what happens if I unplug the external hard drive and resume without it plugged in?

Are there any other risks around this I should be aware of?

Comment: This is offtopic in AskUbuntu. Please consider asking this question in http://serverfault.com or http://www.superuser.com

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu does not unmount the drives - but I think it does flush the cache first. (not an answer as I'm unsure)

Comment: Thou shalt not play with your hardware while thyst power is on.

Comment: @NlightNFotis, I don't see why this is off topic on AskUbuntu as the question depends on the OS. Anyways, this is definitely off topic on ServerFault where you are suggesting the OP to move the question.

Comment: @NLightNFotis: if he asked here he is certainly running Ubuntu on his machine... I don't think it is necessary for him to say that or tag it (all questions here should be tagged ubuntu?), please don't forget AU is linked in Ubuntu site as a support place. His question depends on the OS too, not only hardware because what happens when you suspend depends on what the OS do. I agree it is related to hardware sites too but it is NOT off topic on AU in my opinion.

Comment: I've edited the question clarifying I'm asking about Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu will not unmount the drive, even this one or any other, and if you unplug it and boot the system up later if you try to access it an error will occur, and you might lose some data, by corruption.